# Classification with confidence value

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification

I am using LDA (Matlab machine learning toolbox) to classify different type of wines based on NMR spectra.  The classifier is trained on samples coming from 3 different types. I would like to manage the case where a wine is tested and is not coming from any of these 3 types or it is far from their distributions.

For instance, in the figure below we can see the boundaries and the sample distributions. In this case the posterior probability will be the same for the cross and square markers. They will be both tagged as coming from type 1. We should except that the square is rejected because it is too far from the gaussian distribution of type 1.

How can I have a classification with a confidence value? For example the cross would be tagged as type 1 with a confidence of 95% and the square as type 1 with confidence of <1% and thus rejected.

[image: image link]

Comment: Please add the relevant code and data.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you already know the sample distributions?

Comment: Yes I have a good knowledge of the sample distributions. They follow pretty closely a multivariate normal distribution.